# How would i make this program loop the main twice?

Tags: c, file

I need my program to create two different text files (midinotes1 & midinotes2) and store two bits of data inside them to be read later on. is there an efficient way without copying the code? i understand i need to have filepointer1 writing to midinotes1 and filepointer2 writing to midinotes2 but i dont know how to make my program do that?
Thanks for any advice!

```
#include "aservelibs/aservelib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

float mtof(int note, float frequency);

int main()
{
    FILE *textFilePointer;
    FILE *textFilePointer2;
    int note;
    int velocity;
    int program;
    int counter = 0;
    char user;
    float frequency;


    do

    {

        printf("Press R to Record (R) or (X) to Exit: \n");
        scanf(" %c", &user);

        if (user == 'r' || user == 'R')
        {
            textFilePointer = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "w");
            counter = 0;

            if (textFilePointer == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error Opening file.\n");
            }

            else
            {
                do
                {
                    note = aserveGetNote();
                    velocity = aserveGetVelocity();
                    if (velocity > 0)
                    {
                        fprintf(textFilePointer, "%d\n, %d\n", note, velocity);
                        counter++;

                    }
                    program = aserveGetProgram();

                } while (counter < 16);
                fclose(textFilePointer);

            }
        }

        else if(user == 'x' || user == 'X')
            break;

    } while(user != 'x' || user != 'X');
    return 0;

}



float mtof(int note, float frequency)
{
    frequency = 440.0 * pow(2, (note-69) / 12.0);
    printf("%d\n", note);
    return frequency;
}
```

Comment: `two bits of data` ? bits mean something different here in SO

Comment: Can you try to create another filepointer, and then do fprintf() twice, one to each filepointer.

Comment: @ArjunSreedharan well to be more specific 16 numbers get stored into each text file, it works with the first txt file but i cant find a way to make it do the same again into a different txt file

Comment: Start by making much of your `main` into a separate function?

Comment: @dkopen yeah thats what i ended up doing in the end, got there after many hours of frustration!

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = 0;
char filename[128];
do
{
    printf("Press R to Record (R) or (X) to Exit: \n");
    scanf(" %c", &user);

    if (user == 'r' || user == 'R')
    {
        snprintf(filename, 120, "notes%d.txt", (index+1));
        textFilePointer = fopen(filename, "w");
        counter = 0;

        if (textFilePointer == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error Opening file.\n");
        }

        else
        {
            do
            {
                // your work
            } while (counter < 16);
            fclose(textFilePointer);
            index++;
        }
    }
    else if(user == 'x' || user == 'X')
        break;

} while(user != 'x' || user != 'X');
return 0;
```

Comment: just updated this answer after testing. looks like it should suit your use case

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    FILE *textFilePointer;
    char filename[100];
    int note;
    int velocity;
    int program;
    int counter = 0;
    char user;
    float frequency;
    int sample = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Press R to Record (R) or (X) to Exit: \n");
        scanf(" %c", &user);
        if (user == 'r' || user == 'R')
        {
            sample++;
            sprintf(filename, "/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes%d.txt", sample);
            textFilePointer = fopen(filename, "w");
            counter = 0;

            if (textFilePointer == NULL)
                printf("Error Opening file.\n");
            else
            {
                do
                {
                    note = aserveGetNote();
                    velocity = aserveGetVelocity();
                    if (velocity > 0)
                    {
                        fprintf(textFilePointer, "%d\n, %d\n", note, velocity);
                        counter++;
                    }
                    program = aserveGetProgram();
                } while (counter < 16);
                fclose(textFilePointer);
            }
        }
        else if(user == 'x' || user == 'X')
            break;
    } while(user != 'x' || user != 'X');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is what i tried, unfortunately it stores the same information into both text files, this is what i dont know how to change

Comment: @Luke Nicholls you didn't say *what* you wanted to store except *two bits of data*. Perhaps you want the `note` in one file and the `velocity` in another, in which case simple mods to my code will do the trick.

Comment: sorry i may not have explained clearly enough, i want to store note data and velocity data into one text file, then ask the user to record again, and store a different set of note and velocity data into a seperate .txt file which would be midinotes2.txt (the data is recieved from the user when he presses notes on a keyboard and stored into the txt file)

Comment: @LukeNicholls is this better?